# Merging pandas dataframes and keeping the rows where merge criterium does not match

Tags: python, pandas

I have these two dataframes:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['A0', 'A1', 'A2'],'B': ['B0', 'B1', 'B2']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['A0', 'A1', 'A3'],'B': ['B0', 'B1', 'B2']})
```

I would like to merge these two dataframes now by the entries in column `'A'`. But I do not want to keep the rows which match but the ones which do not match to each other.

That means, I would like to get a new dataframe which looks like this one:

```
df_new = pd.DataFrame({'A':['A3'], 'B':['B2']})
```

How could I do this?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What about `how='outer'` in your `pd.merge()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Merge with outer join gives You similar result:

```
df1.merge(df2, how = 'outer', on = 'A', indicator = True)
```

```
    A  B_x  B_y      _merge
0  A0   B0   B0        both
1  A1   B1   B1        both
2  A2   B2  NaN   left_only
3  A3  NaN   B2  right_only
```

which can be filtered by `query`:

```
df1.merge(df2, how = 'outer', on = 'A', indicator = True).query("_merge != 'both'")
```

```
    A  B_x  B_y      _merge
2  A2   B2  NaN   left_only
3  A3  NaN   B2  right_only
```

Note `indicator = True` created column `_merge` suitable to filter rows.

Comment: Thank you! If I use `on = ['A', 'B']` than the datasets are first merged by `'A'` and afterwards by column `'B'`?

Comment: When a list is passed as `on` argument, then  all columns in list are used as composite key which joins dataframes. It's like `df1.A==df2.A & df1.B == df2.B', similar to SQL join clause in relational databases.

Comment: Ok, that means, that the columns are first joined by the first argument and afterwards by the second, right?

Comment: I'm not sure there is any difference between `on = ['A', 'B']` and `on = ['B', 'A']` when it comes to implementation of this method. From perspective of merge logic and result it's exactly the same.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, using [isin](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html) :

```
df2.loc[~df1.A.isin(df2.A)]

    A   B
2   A3  B2
```